# Does the Bearer Token Refresh Its self?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, bearer-token

Maybe a simple question.

Lets say that the user receives the bearer token and has an expire time of 1 day.

the user makes calls to the web api and then stops making calls say after 6 hours.

Then if the user makes a call to the web api does that auto refresh the token and then the user has another 24 hours to use the token or will it definatly expire based on the first get of the token.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once issued, the token cannot be changed and will be valid until it expires. It doesn't matter how or when the token was used or even if other tokens were requested in the meantime.

Since the token cannot be changed, the expiration of the token cannot be extended. The token can however be revoked before it expires, based on other factors, if the server is configured to do so.

It may not be possible to extend the token itself, but it is possible to request a new token without having to send the credentials.

You can configure the server to add a refresh token to the token. Please note that this is not available for all grant_types. In case of a refresh token the normal token has an extra parameter 'refresh_token' that contains an additional token with its own expiration time. This token can be used once the normal token is expired. In that case a new token can be requested with this refresh token, without having to send the credentials.